# Trace Id not getting sent correctly between spring boot apps

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have a spring boot console app that sends a http request to a spring boot api, the trace id looks correct in the console app, but is a completely different trace id in the api side.  Why would this happen?  Do I need to inject something into the trace context in the console app?  Thanks for any help!
Console app:

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url);
logger.info("right before setting header");

MultiValueMap<String, String> header = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
header.add("X-B3-TraceId", "b3c10720b744fa9d");
header.add("X-B3-SpanId", "b3c10720b744fa9d");

logger.info("right before rest template");
restTemplate
  .exchange(builder.build(false).toUriString(), HttpMethod.POST,
  new HttpEntity<>("some request body", header), String.class);

logger.info("after rest template");
```

console app log(b3c10720b744fa9d is expected trace id):

```
  2020-11-13T18:49:41.686  INFO [-,b3c10720b744fa9d,,] 16268 --- [           main] c.m.f.s.common.impl.TrackingServiceImpl  : right before setting header
  2020-11-13T18:49:41.687  INFO [-,b3c10720b744fa9d,,] 16268 --- [           main] c.m.f.s.common.impl.TrackingServiceImpl  : right before rest template
```

api:

```
  @PostMapping("/trace")
  public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity postTracking(
      @RequestBody String jsonRequest, HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {

      List<String> headers = Collections.list(httpRequest.getHeaderNames());
      headers.forEach(header -> logger.info("Header {} Value {}", header, httpRequest.getHeader(header)));
```

api logs (now showing 221cd9ce3908aa1a as trace id):

```
2020-11-15 17:19:12.814  INFO [-,221cd9ce3908aa1a,221cd9ce3908aa1a,false] 22372 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] c.m.f.t.controller.TrackingController    : Header accept Value text/plain, application/json, application/cbor, application/*+json,
  2020-11-15 17:19:12.815  INFO [-,221cd9ce3908aa1a,221cd9ce3908aa1a,false] 22372 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] c.m.f.t.controller.TrackingController    : Header content-type Value text/plain;charset=UTF-8
  2020-11-15 17:19:12.815  INFO [-,221cd9ce3908aa1a,221cd9ce3908aa1a,false] 22372 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] c.m.f.t.controller.TrackingController    : Header x-b3-traceid Value 221cd9ce3908aa1a
  2020-11-15 17:19:12.815  INFO [-,221cd9ce3908aa1a,221cd9ce3908aa1a,false] 22372 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] c.m.f.t.controller.TrackingController    : Header x-b3-spanid Value 221cd9ce3908aa1a
  2020-11-15 17:19:12.815  INFO [-,221cd9ce3908aa1a,221cd9ce3908aa1a,false] 22372 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] c.m.f.t.controller.TrackingController    : Header x-b3-sampled Value 0
```

Comment: You haven't provided any information on the Sleuth version. Are you sure you're using the latest stable release?

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak I'm using I'm using 2.1.2

Comment: That's very old and unsupported. Please upgrade to the latest version